# How to remove pin feature from VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I work with code and scroll down a little some parts of code which are higher in hierarchy get pinned on top of tab with the line beneath it unless I scroll up to that point again. Is it possible to disable that feature?

I've searched through settings but couldn't find one that I need.

[image: lines 2-15 are pinned when I scroll down]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for this setting.

```
"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false
```

Add this to your settings.json.

Alternatively, you can go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl + , on Windows/Linux or Cmd + , on macOS), search for editor.stickyScroll.enabled, and uncheck the box next to it.

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDaXw.png)

This will disable the sticky scroll feature.